How does an ethernet controller work?
How does ethernet controller or a network interface card work?
I'm a software engineer so have little background on electronics. I've seen some videos from Ben Eater to understand some basics. How would someone start to learn this at a high level?
Any recommendation is much appreciated.

Are you familiar with the OSI model / network stacks?

... and have you looked at any datasheets for any ethernet controller? Specifically, their block diagram?

Yes, but I want to understand the PHY part. I understand the networking and the software stack to a degree.

@Colin This yes and no. I've tried a few times but seems a bit hard. Is there any better way to start or a simple version of an ethernet controller?

@codefast Perhaps start by looking at a PHY for a much simpler interface, to understand the basics, before diving headfirst into something as complicated as ethernet.

Thank you for your answer. Do you have a source for a simple PHY?

The physical layer of the OSI model is quite literally the physical bits being transmitted from device to device, a binary waveform. It's responsible for handling bit synchronization and transmission rate and direction. If you happen to play music, it would be like a composer describing which music instruments play what notes, how fast and loud to play those notes.

You are talking about the whole ethernet controller and then about PHY - they are usually two completely separate chips on a say network adapter - the controller might need a copper PHY or fiber PHY depending on what media you plan to communicate with. The point being, you tell in software to the ethernet controller to send out a packet, and out it goes via the PHY chipset to the medium.

Start with reviewing the OSI model. The part of this 7-layer burrito you're probably wondering about is Layer 1, the Physical layer or PHY.
Essentially, the Data Link Layer (DLL, Layer 2) connects to the PHY Layer, which in turn encodes and decodes signals onto the communications medium. In Ethernet the physical medium is most commonly copper wire, although optical networks are a thing too.
Wired Ethernet uses a variety of coding methods to put signals onto the wire, which have steadily increased in speed and efficiency as electronics have evolved.
Some example wired Ethernet codings in use today:

10Base-T uses Manchester 2-level coding
100Base-T uses MLT-3 3-level coding
1000Base-T uses PAM-5 5-level coding

10Base-T and 100Base-T have separate transmit and receive pairs, so need at least two pairs to operate (we'll revisit this below.)
1000Base-T uses four pairs, but also brings in a new party trick: full duplex. 1000Base-T uses a technique borrowed from the early days of telephone: a 'hybrid' circuit to separate transmit from receive from the same wire.
Essentially, the 'hybrid' subtracts out the transmitter's own signal, leaving only the receive, much in the same way as the telephone hybrid cancels out your own voice from the receiver in your ear.
Ethernet or telephone, the result is the same: with the 'hybrid' doing its job, the receiver only "hears" the far end conversation, allowing reliable reception of the far-end signal.
Unlike a telephone, in an Ethernet PHY the 'hybrid' function isn't a circuit by itself, but is part of the PHY's mixed-signal and DSP functions. The transmit information is fed back to the receiver and subtracted out.
Slower Ethernets can benefit from this trick too. A variant of 100Base-T called One Pair Ethernet is becoming more popular in industrial and automotive. It's similar to what's used in HDMI / HEC that supports Ethernet. These standards use just one pair in full duplex, and like 1000Base-T use a 'hybrid' to split transmit from receive.
Channel coding, 'hybrid', driving and receiving... where is all this magic done? In the PHY of course, a mixed-signal block equipped with some robust DSP capability and an ADC/DAC pair to deal with the analog side. This PHY block is usually instanced as a hardened macro inside of an IC, although PHYs are available as standalone chips as well.
So we have a PHY doing all the mixed-signal stuff. How does it connect to Layer 2, the DLL? Common ways include:
10Base, 100Base:

MII (4 bits in each direction)
RMII (2 bits in each direction, double-data-rate)

1000Base and above:

RGMII (4 bits in each direction, double-data-rate)
SGMII (serial, one bit in each direction).

So we have our PHY happily connected to the link. But we're not quite done. Ethernet also provisions endpoints with electrical isolation. This circuitry is commonly called the 'magnetics', a passive block which is a set of transformers that couple the PHY signals to and from the wire. These magnetics prevent any stray currents from getting into the attached devices, as well as suppressing noise. These magic transformers are usually hidden away in the RJ45 'magjack', or may be separate modules interposed between the PHY and RJ45.
